# How can I move my inbox to different folder

Tags: c#, email, outlook, office-interop

How can I move my inbox's emails to a different folder. I can create a folder in outlook. But i can't move emails.
How can i handle this?

Here is the code I've tried:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application oApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace oNamespace = oApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder oInbox = oNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folders oFolders = oInbox.Folders;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder oPersonal = oFolders.Add("My Folder");
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb610835.aspx). According to that, you can access the collection of items contained within a folder. You can also add items to a folder. So you might be able to manually move them. Alternately, there are various methods for copying or moving folders. I daresay you will find what you require in there.